# Does the booking service usually save your credit card information and share it with the hotel?

Tags: bookings, accommodation, booking.com

From [this post on Facebook](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10213044667605312&id=1051442011), Agoda (and its sister site Booking.com) saved his credit card information and shared it with the hotel he had chosen.

[image]

My friend also shared the same experience when she stayed in Myanmar, when she wanted to extend the stay, the hotel's staff pulled the paper with all of her credit card information to charge her additional cost.

Is this practice common in booking services?

Second question (should this question be moved to Law SE?). From [what I read in Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/155672/94471), those services aren't allowed to save this information (I will link to IS SE later). Can we do anything to prevent this practice?

Comment: Kind of shocking that they would do this! Also that the photo provided just propagated the issue unless the card was cancelled.

Comment: @Itai the card holder shared the information himself, I think he had it cancelled

Comment: By the way, credit cards company only require the use of a CVC code when the card is not present, so for online or phone transactions. For those, they also require the CVC code not to be stored *after* the transaction has been made.

Comment: From what I read on Information Security SE, they isn't allowed to save full number of credit card either, they can save at most 6 first and 4 last numbers.

Comment: @Itai merchants do not *have* to use the CVC code at all - Amazon doesn't.  They accept the additional risk of not doing so, but make no mistake, there is no *requirement* by card companies to use it, just a requirement to use it if you as a merchant want to shift liability elsewhere.

Comment: @Danh Depends on the level of PCIDSS you want to adhere to - there are levels where you can store all the card details.

Comment: @Moo if you store all the card details, PCI DSS also lists conditions on *how* you must store and distribute them. Having sheets of paper with all the data in plain text is not secure storage. If the merchant has a printout like this (or even the ability to make a printout like this) is an indication that it's violating PCI DSS requirements.

Comment: @Peteris yup, I agree, but the comment I was responding to said storage of the whole number isn't allowed, and this isn't really the place to go into a full blown deep dive into the intricacies of PCIDSS, just the dispelling of a few myths 

Comment: I need to admit that I haven't read that standard, I will read it tonight. Anyway, in this case, which party was wrong? Agoda or the hotel?

Comment: For what it’s worth, I’ve had booking services give my credit card details to both airlines and hotels for charges. (Sometimes there are two charges, one by the airline/hotel, and a separate smaller charge for the booking site’s portion of the fee.) They don’t all do this, but if you use enough different booking sites to get deals, you will encounter this practice. Can’t say whether it’s “common.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, almost every single hotel booking service will pass your credit card to the hotel as it lets them place a hold on your credit card in advance or charge it if you don't show up. Some services might be a bit smarter and let the hotel charge you without letting them see the actual card number, which would be more secure.

Overall I wouldn't worry about it. If you see a fraudulent charge simply block your card and ask the bank for a refund. You as a consumer carry zero risk as long as you notice the fraud on time.